# Non-Interacting electrons in a Periodic Potential_by Marder

Tags: condensed-matter

I am reading Condensed Matter Physics, Second edition by Michael P. Marder http://library.lol/main/5C7EF76AC33A06D04EE3FBFEFC79538C. I do not know how can we change the index $K to K - K'$ in the eq(7.14). Where K is a reciprocal space vector. Why it is allowed to change K? What are we doing by changing K?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's an infinite sum. Aslong as you sum over all reciprocal lattice vectors the sum is identical. If you just look at the sum then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{K=-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(k - K' - K) U_K = \sum_{K = -\infty}^{\infty} \psi(k - (K + K')) U_{K}
\end{align*}
so letting $n = K - K'$ with the lower limit becoming $n = -\infty - K' = -\infty$ and the upper limit $n = K - K' = \infty -K' = \infty$ the sum becomes
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(k - K' - n) U_{n} &= \sum_{K=-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(k - K' - K + K') U_{K - K'}\\
 &= \sum_{K=-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(k - K) U_{K-K'}
\end{align*}

Comment: can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: I added some more details